# I need to change state of calendar based on checkbox checked in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tkcalendar

I'm writing and a part of it is a function program that disables or enables the calendar in tkinter, depending whether or not the checkbox is checked or not. Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *


    class Checkbox:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.checkbuttonVar = IntVar()
            self.calendarLabel = Checkbutton(master, text="Set deadline:", variable=self.checkbuttonVar,
                                             command=self.checkcheck)
            self.calendarLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10, sticky=W)

            self.datePick = Calendar(master, date_pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
            self.datePick.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=6, sticky=N + W + S + E)

        def checkcheck(self):
            if self.checkbuttonVar.get() == True:
                self.datePick(state='disabled')
            else:
                print('Not check')
    root = Tk()

    b = Checkbox(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

When I check the checkbox I get a TypeError: 'Calendar' object is not callable (I realize that it's probably the stupidest way to do it, but it's the first time I am actually trying to do something like that so please bear with me). Is there any option to change the state of the calendar? The only option I came with is:

```
def checkcheck(self):
    if self.checkbuttonVar.get() == True:
        self.datePick = Calendar(root, date_pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
        self.datePick.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=6, sticky=N + W + S + E)
    else:
        self.datePick = Calendar(root, date_pattern="mm/dd/yyyy", state='disabled')
        self.datePick.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=6, sticky=N + W + S + E)
```

It kinda does what it's supposed to, but I am not satisfied with this solution and I can see that the program refreshes every time i check the button which isn't very good looking. I would be very thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I am an idiot, all I had to do is this:

```
def checkcheck(self):
    if self.checkbuttonVar.get() != True:
        self.datePick.configure(state="disabled")
    else:
        self.datePick.configure(state="normal")
```

And it works as intented.